# siunitx using wrong \mathrm with eulervm and mathpazo

Tags: siunitx, mathpazo, eulervm

By loading both mathpazo and eulervm, the units are written in the euler mathfont when using siunitx and not in upright roman font. Even if it's explicitly set in `sisetup` :

```
unit-math-rm=\mathrm
```

I'm using Mac TexLive 2016, all packages updated. When `\mathrm` is used regularly in math mode, it works as expected. So there must be some issue how `siunitx` uses `\mathrm`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
%commenting eulervm out prints units right again
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{5}{m/s}
\end{document}
```

[image: with eulervm]

as opposed to

[image: without eulervm]

Comment: Does `\sisetup{mode=text}` give you the desired results?

Comment: @AndrewSwann: Yes, that works. I tested your proposition. You should transfer your comment into an answer.

Comment: OK I forgot that. I'm using the option `euler-digits` as well. And then text modes doesn't show the euler digits, which would be nice.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer The canonical answer from the package author below is better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is 'by design': `eulervm` sets up letters in `\mathnormal` which are very different from `\mathrm`, so `siunitx` does

```
\sisetup{math-rm = \mathnormal}
```

at the start of the document *unless* the user has changed it from the standard value of `\mathrm`. You can override this at the start of the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{math-rm = \mathrm}}
\begin{document}
\SI{5}{m/s} $5\nobreak\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, by using `\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{unit-math-rm=\mathrm}}` I get the expected result. Thank you, never would have thought of the `\AtBeginDocument`